# Swarm: Get Node Ip and Container IP from service

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

how could i get nodes ip and container ip (running on manager(s) and workers(s) node(s) ) from a created service?
I'd like to inspect this for studying round robin load balancing of docker swarm engine and develop a new load balancing.

Answer (score 9):

To get the ***node IP address*** you can use below command:

`docker node inspect self --format '{{ .Status.Addr  }}'`

To get the ***service IP address***, Just add service-id in the end, like:

`docker node inspect self --format '{{ .Status.Addr  }}' service-id`

To get the ***container IP address***, use:

`docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' container-id`

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you mean getting all this information on your terminal using docker command, for a programming language integration check [docker-py](https://github.com/docker/docker-py)

## Containers

To get managers and workers info you can use docker node command:

```
docker node ls
```

Gives you details on each node, for example:

```
ID                            HOSTNAME            STATUS              AVAILABILITY        MANAGER STATUS
j74jxqb4wz38l2odl2seiiuzh *   db-cluster-1        Ready               Active              Leader
```

As you can see it also includes a "manager status" field

## Swarm nodes

```
docker service ps <SERVICE-NAME>
```

Gives you a list of each service node, its ID and status, for example:

```
ID                  NAME                     IMAGE                         NODE                DESIRED STATE       CURRENT STATE         ERROR                       PORTS
ypd65x4i06nn        db-cluster.1       severalnines/mariadb:latest   db-cluster-1        Running             Running 2 hours ago                               
278rdv7m4015        db-cluster.2       severalnines/mariadb:latest   db-cluster-1        Running             Running 2 hours ago                               
z9zr6xgnyuob        db-cluster.3       severalnines/mariadb:latest   db-cluster-1        Running             Running 2 hours ago
```

then you can use inspect to get more detailed information on any object, for example:

```
docker inspect ypd65x4i06nn
```

check NetworksAttachments section to get network details

Answer (score 0):

for getting the node IP address, the value is in different places depending on if the node is a worker or a manager.

```bash
docker node inspect node1 --pretty
ID:         0lkd116rve1rwbvfuonrfzdko
Hostname:               node1
Joined at:              2022-09-18 16:16:28.6670527 +0000 utc
Status:
 State:         Ready
 Availability:          Active
 Address:       192.168.64.5
Manager Status:
 Address:       192.168.64.5:2377
 Raft Status:       Reachable
 Leader:        No
...
```

here node2 is manager

```bash
docker node inspect node2 --pretty
ID:         u8tfyh5txt5qecgsi543pnimc
Hostname:               node2
Joined at:              2022-09-19 09:05:57.91370814 +0000 utc
Status:
 State:         Ready
 Availability:          Active
 Address:       0.0.0.0. <--------- CHECK HERE ---
Manager Status:
 Address:       192.168.64.6:2377
 Raft Status:       Reachable
 Leader:        Yes
...
```

But you can make use of the [go template syntax](https://pkg.go.dev/text/template#section-documentation):

```bash
> docker node inspect node2 \
--format 'worker addr:{{ .Status.Addr  }} {{printf "\n"}}manager addr: {{ .ManagerStatus.Addr  }}'
worker addr:0.0.0.0
manager addr: 192.168.64.6:2377
```